# How to setup GRPC transport credentials with server behind reverse proxy

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I'm running a GRPC server. Today, it has its own certificate as part of the application code. I'd like to move certificate handling and TLS termination to a reverse proxy.

Server looks like this (since no TLS involved behind the proxy):

```
grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(
    grpc.Creds(insecure.NewCredentials()),
    grpc.KeepaliveParams(keepalive.ServerParameters{
        MaxConnectionIdle: 30 * time.Second,
    }),
)
```

Client dial looks like this (since it needs to talk TLS imho):

```
creds := credentials.NewTLS(new(tls.Config))
conn, err := grpc.Dial(host, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds))
```

This doesn't work:

```
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: EOF"
```

Changing the client to use `insecure.NewCredentials()` instead of empty `tls.Config` fails as well:

```
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "error reading server preface: read tcp 192.168.178.137:61666->66.241.124.2:8080: read: connection reset by peer"
```

Should any of these methods work for GRCP server behind TLS-terminating reverse proxy? What is the correct way to configure transport credentials for this deployment scenario?

Comment: try using `grpc.Creds(nil)` on the server

Comment: Still leads to `rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: EOF"`

Comment: What reverse proxy do you use? If it is NGINX, make sure you use [`stream`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html) config, not `http`

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it: `grpc.Creds(...)` must be removed altogether. The other missing piece- as the app is running on fly.io- is adding the required ALPN handler to the reverse proxy configuration:

```
[services.ports.tls_options]
alpn = ["h2"]
```